# Cannot install laravel oci8

Tags: laravel, oci8

the `composer require yajra/laravel-oci8:^8` command is giving me the following error:

```
C:\Users\yö\PhpstormProjects\BRP>composer require yajra/laravel-oci8:^8
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update yajra/laravel-oci8
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires yajra/laravel-oci8 8 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-oci8[v8.0.0].
    - yajra/laravel-oci8 v8.0.0 requires ext-oci8 >=2.0.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's oci8 extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\PHP74\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

> Windows 10
> PHP 7.4.6
> Laravel 8.26.1
> PHP Storm 2020.2.3

I am not using XAMMP or WAMP

I hope someone can help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `yajra/laravel-oci8 v8.0.0 requires ext-oci8 >=2.0.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's oci8 extension` tells what you need to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the OCI8 PHP extension, So follow these steps:

1. From http://pecl.php.net/package/oci8 download exact version, for you must be php_oci8-2.2.0, unzip it and copy to PHP ext folder, for you its in "C:\php74\ext"
2. Un-Comment "extension=php_oci8_11g.dll" in php.ini and restart Apache or any other web server that you are using
3. Check php_info(), oci8 should be enabled.
4. Run `composer require yajra/laravel-oci8:^8` command again.

Comment: Do i copy the whole unzipped folder into php\ext or the files inside?

Comment: You are using windows OS so download dll files of extension and then copy them to your PHP extension folder
https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.2.0/windows

Comment: If your database is on a different computer, then don't forget to install Oracle Instant Client so PHP OCI8 can find the necessary Oracle 'client' libraries that handle the network connection to the database.  On Windows you also need the VS redistributables.  The Instant Client download page has details.  Use either the 32 or 64 bit Instant Client to match the architecture of your PHP.  Personally I would use a more recent PHP OCI8 DLL than the 11g one.

Comment: @chrisopher the VS redistributable was the missing ingredient, you and pejman kheyri helped me a lot. You made a young students day. God bless you :)

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you. 
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

download extensions with suitable php version in https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oci8/

extract and copy all the .dll files to /xampp/php/ext

download instant client oracle with suitable OS and PHP version in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html

extract and copy all the dll files to /xampp/apache/bin/ and copy it to /xampp/php/

install https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8