# PHP does not recognize an oci8 extension

Tags: php, oci8

I'm using

PHP version 7.4

windows 10

Laravel 5.7

---

I'm trying to perform a composer install on the repository, but the following error appears:

> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires yajra/laravel-oci8 5.7.* -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-oci8[v5.7.0, ..., 5.7.x-dev].
> - yajra/laravel-oci8[v5.7.0, ..., 5.7.x-dev] require ext-oci8 >=2.0.0 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's oci8 extension.

I tried to follow the step by step of this post: [Cannot install laravel oci8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060079/cannot-install-laravel-oci8)

But it still didn't work.

Comment: Try installing OCI8 using the OCI8 2.2.0 DLLs from https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8  You will also need Oracle Instant Client (a recent version should be fine)

Answer (score 0):

PHP OCI8 on PECL supports PHP 7 (and older versions - see
PECL page to install on older PHP versions).
Try uninstalling OCI8. Check if you don't have multiple versions of PHP - the difference in path names makes me think you have them.

Comment: This is outdated information.  The first things in the [PECL description](https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8) are the instructions for installing with PHP 8 and 8.1: "Use 'pecl install oci8' to install for PHP 8.1. Use 'pecl install oci8-3.0.1' to install for PHP 8.0."